Poetry - unable to lock a wordninja dependency
I have a very weird issue that I cannot solve. I am using poetry as dependency manager in my application and so far I have been using it without issues. However I have run into an issue after adding wordninja = "2.0.0" dependency. I am unable to generate the lock file. After running poetry lock I a get a failed to query /usr/local/bin/python3 with code -9 which from reading on it would indicate some sort of OOM but that is not happening here to my knowledge.
I know for a fact that if I remove this dependecy I can lock the file without an issue. I have tried deleting lock file. Recreating the venv and clearing all poetry cache but without any progress. Does anyone have any idea what this could be.
When I run the command in verbose I get:
   1  ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py:381 in from_exe
       379│
       380│         env = os.environ if env is None else env
     → 381│         proposed = from_exe(cls, app_data, exe, env=env, raise_on_error=raise_on_error, ignore_cache=ignore_cache)
       382│
       383│         if isinstance(proposed, PythonInfo) and resolve_to_host:

  RuntimeError

  failed to query /usr/local/bin/python3 with code -9

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/virtualenv/discovery/cached_py_info.py:33 in from_exe
       29│     env = os.environ if env is None else env
       30│     result = _get_from_cache(cls, app_data, exe, env, ignore_cache=ignore_cache)
       31│     if isinstance(result, Exception):
       32│         if raise_on_error:
    →  33│             raise result
       34│         logging.info("%s", result)
       35│         result = None
       36│     return result
       37│

